# Reading multiple lines from an input file

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream

I have an input file that has multiple lines (arrays) of `int`s.  I don't know how to read each array separately.  I can read all the `int`s and store them into a single array, but I don't know how to read each array from the input file individually.  Ideally, I want to run the array's through different algorithms and get execution times on them.

My input file:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 22, 30, 12
[66, 50, 10]
```

Input stream:

```
ifstream inputfile;
inputfile.open("MSS_Problems.txt");
string inputstring;
vector<int> values;

while(!inputfile.eof()){
        inputfile >> inputstring;
        values.push_back(convert(inputstring));
}
inputfile.close();
```

Convert function:

```
for(int i=0; i<length; ++i){
    if(str[i] == '['){
        str[i] = ' ';
    }else if(str[i] == ','){
        str[i] = ' ';
    }else if(str[i] == ']'){
        str[i] = ' ';
    }
}
return  atoi(str.c_str());
```

Should I set up a `bool` function to check if there are brackets and then end there?  If I do that, how do I tell the program to start reading at the next open bracket and store it in a new vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want?

data

```
 [1,2,3,4,5]
 [6,22,30,12]
 [66,50,10]
```

input stream:

```
 std::ifstream inputfile;
 inputfile.open("MSS_Problems.txt");
 std::string inputstring;
 std::vector<std::vector<int>> values;

 while(!inputfile.eof()){
        inputfile >> inputstring;
        values.push_back(convert(inputstring));
 }
 inputfile.close();
```

Convert function:

```
 std::vector<int> convert(std::string s){
      std::vector<int> ret;
      std::string val;
      for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
          /*include <cctype> to use isdigit */ 
          if(std::isdigit(str[i]))
             val.push_back(str[i]); //or val += str[i];
          if(str[i] == ',' || str[i] == ']') 
          {
              // the commma and end bracket tells us we are at the end of our value
             ret.push_back(std::atoi(val.c_str())); //so get the int
             val.clear(); //and reset our value. 
          }
      }
       return ret;
 }
```

[std::isdigit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) is a helpful function that will let us know that the character we are looking at is numeric or not, so you can safely ignore your open brackets.

With that you would access each line of int's as a [multidemensional vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/833/). Alternatively if your goal is to have one vector of all the integers stored in the data then your input stream loop should be

```
 vector<int> values;

 while(!inputfile.eof()){
        inputfile >> inputstring;
        std::vector<int> line = convert(inputstring);
        //copy to back inserter requires including both <iterator> and <algorithm>
        std::copy(line.begin(),line.end(),std::back_inserter(values)); 
 }
 inputfile.close();
```

Which is a good way to learn to use [Copy to back_inserter](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/).

Comment: The only issue with that is sometimes the array will take up multiple lines.  So I might have 20+ int's that will wrap down to the next line.

Comment: @shelum is your editor set to use word wrap? if so then set it not to.